# bash script to get asbolute diretory of script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using the following to get the absolute path

```
root_dir=$(cd `dirname $0` && pwd)
```

print

```
/home/pi/scripts/bin
```

How do I modify the line to go back one directory. `/home/pi/scripts`

Comment: Determining the location of your script using `$0` may not always be reliable - further reading [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you would do manually:

```
root_dir=$(cd `dirname $0`/.. && pwd)
```

But probably you will like an easiest way. You don't need to change folder and print the current folder, just get the name you need and add the parent path:

```
root_dir=$(dirname $0)/..
```

Comment: Using the first gave me what i was looking for `/home/pi/scripts` the second gave me `bin/..`

Comment: And that string is the parent of your script seen from your current location (relative path). If you want and absolute path, you can try `root_dir=$(readlink -f $(dirname $0)/..)`